# Google Maps is loading endlessly in JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile

I am using google maps in one of my jquery mobile pages, and instead of loading the whole maps javascript files on every page, I've included them into the page in which google maps is used.

But when I navigate to the page, the loading spinner is spinning and spinning around but nothing happens. When I delete the gmaps code everything works fine.

I use [this plugin](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/wiki/jquery_ui_map_v_3_tutorial) so my code looks like that:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1" data-theme="a">
    <?php include "components/site_header.php"; ?>
    <!-- Scripts for Maps -->
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="library/jquery.ui.map.full.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--.................-->
    <div data-role="content">
               <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%;height:250px"></div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function() {
                        var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?=$lat;?>, <?=$lon;?>);
                        $('#map_canvas').gmap({'center': LatLng});
                    });
                    </script>
               </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT** The code is working when I call the webpage directly (over the URL). But it is loading endlessly when I navigate to it through the website...

**EDIT2** Got the code to work. Removed the plugin which I stated above and added the Google Maps JS file BEFORE the Jquery and Jquery Mobile JS. And my code looks now like this:

```
            <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%;height:250px"></div>
               <script type="text/javascript"> 
               var address = '<?php echo $info['pr_city'].", ".$info['pr_zip'].", ".$info['pr_street'].", ".$info['pr_nr']; ?>';

               var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), { 
                   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                   zoom: 15
               });

               var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

               geocoder.geocode({
                  'address': address
               }, 
               function(results, status) {
                  if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                     new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                        map: map
                     });
                     map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                  }
               });
               </script>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console? Also, are you watching the network connections being made when the error occurs? Maybe an asset isn't loading correctly... I imagine that the relative URL you're using for one of the JS includes could create issues with jQuery Mobile and the way it handles `<baseurl>`.

Comment: thanks for your answers. fixed the problem by calling the google maps js BEFORE the jquery and jquery mobile. now the map is not showing correctly (just quarter of the size) but that is another problem...

Comment: I am glad you have successfully solved your problem. And Jasper tnx for a tip, an excellent solution in case header and footer height is constant.